# Custom Components in Crafty.js

Tags: craftyjs

I am new to Crafty.js. I am currently working a 2D Top Down RPG using this frame work. I am trying to create a custom component that will contain the Unit's information such as Health, Mana, Name etc. My component's code are as follows:

```
Crafty.c("UnitInfo", {

    init: function() {

        this.bind("EnterFrame", function(){

            console.log("Custom Component Test: " + this.message);

        });

    },

    unitinfo: function(message) {

        this.message = message;

    }

});
```

Then I added this component to a unit which is in my case, an Enemy entity:

```
enemy1 = Crafty.e('Enemy, 2D, Canvas, Color, enemy_default, SpriteAnimation, Solid, Collision, UnitInfo')
         .attr({x: (screenWidth/2) + 150, y: (screenHeight/2) + 150, w: spriteBaseW, h: spriteBaseH, curHealth: 100 })
         .checkHits("Skill")
         .unitinfo("Random Msg")
         .bind("HitOn", function() {

            var rndDmg = 0;

            if(currentSkill==1) rndDmg = skillDamage.skill1;
            else if(currentSkill==2) rndDmg = skillDamage.skill2;
            else if(currentSkill==3) rndDmg = skillDamage.skill3;
            else if(currentSkill==4) rndDmg = skillDamage.skill4;

            rndDmg = randomRange(rndDmg-9,rndDmg);
            this.curHealth -= rndDmg;

            Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Text, Tween")
            .attr({x: this.x, y: this.y})
            .textColor("white")
            .text(rndDmg)
            .textFont({size: "20px"})
            .tween({y: this.y-30, alpha: 0.0}, 2000)
            .bind("TweenEnd", function(){
                this.destroy();
            });

            if(this.curHealth<=0) {

                //this.destroy();
                //console.log("An Enemy was killed!!!!");

            }else{

                console.log("Enemy HP: " + this.curHealth + ", Damage Taken: " + rndDmg);
            }

         })
         .bind("EnterFrame", function() {

            enemyAI(this);

         });
```

When I execute the code, it shows me this error:

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coDEq.png)

I believe that the unitinfo() is properly working as the "Random Msg" is appearing on the console logs and it is being executed every frame. I just don't understand why "this" is being recognized as undefined. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're attempting to call bind on the result of `unitinfo()`, but that method doesn't return the entity.

This is a fundamental aspect of javascript, but it's definitely a gotcha when implementing custom components in Crafty.  From the [docs](http://craftyjs.com/documentation/components.html)

> Keep in mind that the method chaining technique (calling `e.place().color()`) is only possible because we explicitly return this from our custom method. Forgetting to do so can be a common source of errors, so keep that in mind if you get a hard-to-pin-down "method undefined" message.

i.e. when you define a method, you have to explicitly return `this` to use it in this manner.